# Regex to replace full name python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

regex to replace a full name with numbers "FirstName001 LastName001" , I did that and it doesn't work  properly :

```
import re
re.sub('^FirstName[00][01]?[0-9] LastName[00][01]?[0-9]', '  ', my_string)
```

any solution?

Comment: What do you want to replace the matched text with? Just remove the numbers in the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this one:

```
import re 
my_string = "FirstName001 LastName001" 

new_string = re.sub('\d', '', my_string) 
print(new_string)

Out: 'FirstName LastName'


OR 


new_string = re.sub('FirstName|LastName', '', my_string) 
print(new_string)

Out: '001 001'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to replace the whitespace between first name and last name with name then:

```
import re
name = 'FirstName001 LastName001'
r = re.sub('([a-z])|([A-Z])', '', name)
print(r)
```

Output:
'001 001'

And if you want to replace the whitespace in between first and last name with name then:

```
r = re.sub('([a-z])|([A-Z])\s', '', name)
print(r)
```

Output:
'001001'

To get full name:

```
r = re.sub('\d', '', name)
print(r)
```